# How can I use a function in an object returned by the setup function to modify a value in an object returned by the setup function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Now I have the following Vue3 code:

```
<template>
    <div @click="f">
        Comp. {{first}} {{last}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {ref, reactive, toRef, toRefs} from "vue";

export default {
    name: "Comp",

    props: {
        a: {
            type: String
        },
        b: {
            type: Number
        }
    },

    setup() {
        let info = reactive({
            first: "a",
            last: "b"
        });

        return {
            ...toRefs(info),
            f() {
                console.log(this.first.value);
            }
        };
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I expect the f function to output "a", but the f function actually outputs undefined.

When I run the above code and click on the component, the console outputs a Proxy object that wraps the object returned by the setup function.

I'm trying to access the toRefs wrapped 'first' property in the f function through this. The code is: `this.first.value`, But I found that its value is undefined.
Instead, when I use `this.first` I can access the value of the 'first' property just fine. Why is this?
I know that toRefs use the ref method to wrap the contents of a given object, so wouldn't accessing the value of the ref object be through ref.value? Why is it not working here?

Vue version is 3.12.3

Comment: You need to forget about "this" in composition api. You already have info var at hand. Modify it, that's why it exists

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, it's right there in the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#basic-usage) but I didn't realize that it's the answer:

> *refs* returned from `setup` are *automatically shallow unwrapped* when accessed in the template so you do not need to use `.value` when accessing them. They are **also unwrapped** in the same way when accessed on **`this`**.